# jquery timer plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

the link specified below is a jquery timer plugin.

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Also i use the following to start a timer

```
$('#timer').countdown({until: 12,compact: true, description: ' to Go'});
```

My question is how do i deduce that the timer has reached 00:00:00 or the time given has elapsed

Thanks..

Comment: why on earth did you put backticks around the link? do you want people to click it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a callback. This plugin accepts a variable `onExpiry`. Pass that in with a reference to the function you want to call when the timer expires.

```
$('#timer').countdown({until: 12,compact: true, onExpiry:myFunc, description: ' to Go'});
function myFunc() { /* whatever */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

check the documentation..

> onExpiry(function) A callback function
>   that is invoked when the countdown
>   reaches zero. Within the function this
>   refers to the division that holds the
>   widget. No parameters are passed in.
>   Use the expiryText or expiryUrl
>   settings for basic functionality on
>   expiry.
>
> $(selector).countdown({ 
>       until: liftoffTime, onExpiry: liftOff});    function liftOff() { 
>       alert('We have lift off!');  }

Answer (score 1):

the `until` field specifies when the countdown reaches this point, then, specify `onExpiry` callback function.

> From the JS code
>
> **onExpiry**: null, // Callback when the
>   countdown expires -
>   // receives no
>   parameters and 'this' is the
>   containing division

For your function:

```
$('#timer').countdown({until: 12,compact: true, description: ' to Go', onExpiry = executeMyFunction});

function executeMyFunction() {
   alert("Tada!");
}
```